# django radio button on request.POST is not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, radio-button

i am trying to read the value from the radio.input in the form below using

```
def question_detail(request,question_id,quiz_id):
q = Quiz.objects.get(pk = quiz_id)
que = Question.objects.get(pk = question_id)
count = q.question_set.count()
try:
    selected_choice = que.answer_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except(KeyError, Answer.DoesNotExist):
    come = que.rank
    came = come + 1
    later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
    return render(request, 'app/question_detail.html',{'que': que, 'count': count, 'later_question': later_question})
else:
    if selected_choice.correct is True:
        try:
            come = que.rank
            came = come + 1
            later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
        except:
            come = que.rank
            came = come
            later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
    else:
        come = que.rank
        later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=come)
    return render(request, 'app/question_detail.html',{'count': count, 'que': que, 'later_question': later_question})
```

but when i try to access the webpage,it throws an Keyerror,please help

```
<form action="{% url 'app:detail' quiz_id=que.quiz.id question_id=later_question.id%}" method="post">{% csrf_token%}
{% for choice in que.answer_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name='choice' value="{{choice.id}}">
    <label>{{choice.answer}}-{{choice.correct}}-{{choice.rank}}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: add the error traceback here

Comment: There is no traceback because I have also written the code for error

Comment: Just put a line "raise" in your except clause and the error messages will come back.

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /quiz/2/11/

'choice'

Comment: I am assuming you want to display the form with your code - this will through an error because the form data i not yet in the request. You need to make sure you only enter the evaulation of the form via if request.method="POST": see docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: please check this code - https://pastebin.com/14xS55vN

Comment: ,it still return me else:(even if i choose option) @ger.s.brett

Comment: What does selected_choice.correct mean? IShould it not be selected_choice=="correct"?

Comment: '.correct' is a booleanfield , if it is checked means 'True' it will redirect to another question else redirect to same question

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WtQ09nE7 here is my models.py